# Why do I need CORS header to request a downloadable link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I have a link that allows me to download a file when I click on it. Instead of downloading, I am trying to access it with a simple request however I am having CORS problems. I do not have any access to the server side, and therefore everything I have tried so far have failed. If I understand correctly, all suggestions I have found so far needs me to have control over the server (I might be mistaken, but as far as I see server side needs to have a CORS header including my domain or have a jsonp function to be envoked).

Does that mean I am unable to read and parse a file that is already downloadable? If yes, how does it make sense since the file is public and already downloadable when I click the link. Since I am manually able to get the file, shouldn't it be possible to access it with code? Could you suggest me any solution or give something that I can work on? Why the code below do not work as a manual click on the browser would?

```
var urlString = "http://abc.def.com/download?fileid=123&amp;entity_id=123&amp;sid=123";
$.get(urlString, function(data, status){
alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);});
```

Comment: Start learning from [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: I have read that, but isnt it different for a downloadable url? I mean I will be downloading it once I click it, so it feels like it should be possible to get the information instead of downloading it? If its not possible at all unless server side enables it, what is the difference between the request my browser sent when I click, and the request my code sent?

Comment: If I wasnt able to download it, I would understand the protection policy and all but since I know my computer have access to a certain data, why cannot I specify what my computer will do with it?

Comment: It seems that you haven't read that attentively. The point is that most browsers doesn't allow a client script to do request to external resource. And it doesn't matter, is it downloadable or not,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to download the external script by manually clicking on a link to it because, well, you manually clicked it on it! The browser knows that you authorized access to that URL because you clicked a link that pointed to it. But if a bit of JavaScript accesses that URL in the background, the browser can't be so sure the user is okay with that.

You're thinking "I'm just trying to download an innocent file, why does the browser not trust me??" But let's consider a scarier scenario. Let's say, instead of trying to access `http://innocentsite.com/download`, your JavaScript was trying to access `https://bankofamerica.com/initiateMoneyTransfer?recipient=OE1&amount=10000`. Without even knowing it, the user has just let you send $10,000 to yourself since they were logged in on bankofamerica.com.

Now, obviously Bank of America (or any other respectable bank) doesn't allow $10,000 transfers to be initiated like that. But hopefully the example gets the idea across -- it would be very dangerous for webpages to be able to make HTTP requests to other domains. That's why CORS headers are required.

---

Footnote: If you are hosting your own web server, you might look into setting up a proxy. You could have a URL on your website that automatically retrieves the file from the other website, and serves it on your domain. That way, you can retrieve the file without needing the other website to set CORS headers.

Comment: Wow. So the problem is just being able to access a file also allows me to invoke any function in server domain is that right? I thought asking for a public file and invoking a function(or asking for a non public data) would be different things. Its kind of weird to be able to do everything or do nothing at all.

Comment: Yeah, because your browser simply has no way of distinguishing between a URL that downloads an innocent file and a URL that detonates a nuclear warhead. It'd be nice if websites used CORS headers more liberally, but very few webmasters will take the time to do that.

Comment: Can I somehow tell my computer what to do with the file I clicked instead of trying to ask from external website? Like can I tell something equivalent to "when I click this link, dont download the file you will be given but put it in this variable"? It seems like a long shot but I just wanted to ask before giving up on this.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't. But, if you have control of the web server your page is being served on, you could run a proxy on your web server, which would download the file from the other domain, and serve it on your domain.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, it was quite helpful. I will look for another way around.